# Не работает блокировка кнопки перед асинхронным методом и после го выполнения

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

Делаю запрос к сайту, сам запрос длится какое-то время 3 - 5 сек. Чтобы пользователь не тикаk снова по кнопке перед выполнением метода с запросом ее блокирую, а после уже выполнения питаюсь разблокировать. Методы как бы асинхронные но не работает, подскажите что не так сделал?

```
async Task<bool> Test()
{

    try
    {

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://mysitecom/prog-api/ver.php");

        var postData = "v=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(progVer);
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();


        Console.WriteLine("END");
        return true;
    } 
    catch
    {
        return false;
        
    }
    

}

private async void runPoster_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    runPoster.IsEnabled = false;
    await Test();
    runPoster.IsEnabled = true;

}
```

Сейчас вишел с положения таким образом, не знаю на сколько это правильно но все же. Если можно проще подскажите.

```
    async Task<bool> Test()
    {

        runPoster.IsEnabled = false;
        string status = "";

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {

            try
            {

                var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://mysite.com/prog-api/ver.php");

                var postData = "v=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(progVer);
                var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                request.ContentLength = data.Length;

                using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                }

                var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(responseString);
                if (responseString != progVer)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Ваша версия программы устарела, скачайте новую версию!");
                    return;
                }

                status = "1";
                return;

            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Сервис не доступен!");
                return;

            }


        });

        runPoster.IsEnabled = true;
        if (status == "1")
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }


    }


    private async void runPoster_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        bool status = await Test();
        if (status == false)
        {
            return;
        }

        MessageBox.Show("ВСЕ ОК!");


    }
```

Comment: Убрать async у runPoster_Click, выполнить Task без await, и поставить включение кнопки на callback таска.

Comment: Код внутри метода `Test` полностью синхронный.

Comment: 1. `HttpWebRequest` уже давно устарел, и в будущих версиях C# будет вовсе выпилен. Из-за этого вы делаете кучу лишнего, когда как используя современный `HttpClient`, весь ваш метод состоял всего из парочки строк кода. 2. Добавление `async` к методу не делает метод асинхронным, делает его асинхронным именно связка с `async/await`, а у вас ни единого `await` нет в методе, также вы вызываете синхронные версии методов (из документации: `Метод GetResponse выполняет синхронный запрос к ресурсу`).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо за подсказку исправил HttpWebRequest  на HttpClient теперь все работает.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на собственный вопрос.
Сделал так.

```
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

private async Task<bool> CheckVersionAsync(string version)
{
    var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        ["v"] = version
    };
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

    using var response = await client.PostAsync("https://mysite.com/prog-api/ver.php", content);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return responseString == version;
}

private async void runPoster_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    runPoster.IsEnabled = false;

    try
    {
        bool status = await CheckVersionAsync(progVer);

        if (status)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ВСЕ ОК!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ваша версия программы устарела, скачайте новую версию!");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

    runPoster.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

Comment: `HttpClient` должен быть создан только раз, один экземпляр на все время работы приложения. Также мой вам совет, не мешайте все в одну кучу, не мешайте UI с данными, например `runPoster.IsEnabled = false;` это UI, хотите его обновлять, используйте `IProgress` или что-то подобное, либо за пределами метода.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я пока что не в курсе что это. Новичок. Только пробую научится что то делать. Но спасибо за ваши советы, буду читать и изучать.

Comment: `HttpClient client = new HttpClient();` вынесите за пределы метода в класс `private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();`, а из метода удалите. Тогда клиент будет создан только один раз.

Comment: Хотите, вам код в ответе поправлю? Там ещё есть проблема с отловом исключения при обращении к серверу.

Comment: @aepot я его сделал при помощи try catch

Comment: Тогда обновите код в ответе. Потому что отсутсвтвие перехвата в `async void` методе - по сути ошибка. Ещё перемудрили с тру/фолс и работу с ui лучше в обработчик события вынести, а то каша какая-то. Ещё `using` для `IDisposable` пропустили. Ну что, подправить?

Comment: @aepot подправь если не сложно, за одно посмотрю как это правильно делается.

Comment: Подправил. Кстати, несовсем понимаю, зачем серверу отправлять версию, если он тоже версию возвращает. То есть определитесь, где версию сравнивать, на сервере или на клиенте. Если на сервере, то возвращайте какое-нибудь "true/false", а если на клиенте, то зачем POST? Можно переделать с простой GET и сравнивать версию на клиенте точно так же как вы делаете это сейчас. Запрос получится однострочный `string version = await client.GetStringAsync(url);`

Comment: Исправил ещё один недочёт, добавил  `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();` - эта строчка выбросит исключение, если сервер вернул ответ с HTTP ошибкой, например 404 или 500. Без этой строчки у вас будет неверно воспринят ошибочный ответ в случае ответа от сервера статусом, отличным от 200.